# Crack sound when start playing music on Linux mint 18

Tags: audio, linux-mint

I'm having a strange crack-like sound when I start playing any audio in a Linux Mint 18 installation on a notebook connected to an external amplified speaker box.

The crack sound only happens when it's connected to the external speaker. Using the notebook's speaker the sounds behaves normally.

The amplified speaker doesn't have an eletric grounding, yet in windows the crack sound doesn't happen.

Also, after the first crack sound, if I play another music, the crack sounds doesn't happen. Yet if I wait a bit (like 10 secs) and start a sound it happens again.

I'm thinking Mint sound system should have any "sound service" in the background that enters operation when a sound is played causing the crack and then when it's silent for a while it's unloaded from memory. And if you play any sound when this service is active it plays the sound correctly. If it has to load then the crackling sound appears.

I have confirmed the above because I needed to use the notebook in an event, so what I did was using vlc's loop funcion to loop trough 1/2 second of silence in order to keep the sound system active all the time and use Totem to play the musics. When I did this, the sound behaved normally.

Also if I raised the external speaker volume's high enough, after some seconds of silence I could head a low sound like something shutting down, strengthning the "loaded sound server" hypothesis.

So can anybody explain to me what is this thing that is loaded when a music starts playing and unload after some seconds of silence an how can I avoid it from unloading from memory ? Thanks

**Edit**:

I tried the exit-idle-time = -1 configuration, but the problem remained.

I suspected it was any kind of electrical grounding problem, and tried to test this. So I changed the Acer Aspire E14 notebook for a Dell Vostro 3550 that also has mint 18 install. And in the Dell machine the crack sound didn't happen. So It strengthen the eletric grouding hypothesis. 
Another thing I forgot to mention is that these tests were conducted with the computer's AC power unplugged.
As soon as I plugged the power the problem was gone. 
So I concluded that was really a problem of eletric grounding. Maybe Acer has lower standards in their shelling or maybe this is a problem with that specific machine.

Anyway, in windows it doesn't happen, so there must be a way to solve this by software only.

Hope this give some clue to whoever has this problem.

Comment: Known bug of pulseaudio. Don't let him to kill itself! (`exit-idle-time`)